# JVM implementation tests

Tags: jvm

I have been developing grails for some time now, and I keep running into platform dependent behavior. I have found bugs that only happen on legitimate versions of Windows and I have found bugs that only happen on one machine even if I reformat and reinstall some other OS and JVM. My most recent gripe, which I can reproduce on several machines but nobody else can is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884569/grails-println-only-works-sometimes-or-something

Is there some kind of testing or benchmarking suite I can use to see if my JVM is implemented correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Java Compatibility Kit](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/docs/JCK6bUsersGuide/html/p3.html) that has got a huge amounts of tests for JVMs/JDK, but this may be overkill, and it might not be trivial to set up and run.

You have said that:

> I have found bugs that only happen on one machine even if I reformat
>   and reinstall some other os and JVM

How is your program printing out stuff?  Is it to a GUI or console?  If it is a GUI, it might be that there is a compatibility issue with your video card and Java's 2D hardware acceleration.  It might be worth playing around with a few [Java 2D system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html) (try `noddraw` on Windows to turn off all acceleration, play around with opengl settings on 'nix).

Apart from that, you could try running the JVM in interpreted mode (slow!) with -Xint to see if there is a JVM bytecode compilation issue.